# Is there a way to get param passed to a form() to buttonEvent in the same form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

How can i use the 2 list from the Public FormGenSea in the button btAddSeaToDB?

```
    public partial class FormGenSea : Form
    {
        public FormGenSea(List<string> dow, List<string> dtlist)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<string> Selected = dow;
            List<string> Data = dtlist;

        }

        private void btAddSeaToDB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            /*Do some stuff with the 2 list from above */
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should declare the Selected and Data List at the level of the class if you want to use them out of the constructor scope.

Comment: How can i do that, i'm not that skilled in C# so an exemple would be great :) The 2 lists are sent from another form to the new one `FormGenSea() `

Comment: look up how to declare class fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use local variables inside your class and use them after setting them in your constructor
your code will be like this:

```
public partial class FormGenSea : Form
    {
        private List<string> Selected;
        private List<string> Data ;
        public FormGenSea(List<string> dow, List<string> dtlist)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Selected = dow;
            Data = dtlist;

        }

        private void btAddSeaToDB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            /*Do some stuff with the 2 list from above (Data ,Selected ) */
        }
    }
```

Comment: lol i feel dumb -_- ! that's simple, well i spend too much time in this project that i forgot some of the basics! Thx a lot for the reminder!!

Comment: Visual studio must tell you these small things if you focused on the error